# Pronunciation of council/counsellor

Tags: pronunciation

I have heard sometimes the [æ] vowel in either *concil* [kaʊnsl/kounsəl] or *counsellor* [kaʊnsələ(r)/kouns(ə)lər], as in [this British pronunciation](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/counsellor) of *counsellor*. It sounds rather like *cat* [kæt] than *cow* [kau], but I'm not sure if it's really [æ]+[u]. Am I hearing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your link, the [a] from the British /aʊ/ is certainly much *longer* than the American one, and perhaps a little bit more front, but not to the point that I would classify it as [æ].

If you are interested in hearing what that diphthong would sound like with a true [æ] nucleus, it is supposedly realized as [æɔ] in *Australian* English ([here](http://clas.mq.edu.au/speech/phonetics/phonetics/ausenglish/) is one source on that, and [here](http://alt-usage-english.org/audio_archive.shtml) is an archive of recordings of a text from different English dialects, including Australian).

A similar pronunciation also occurs in certain regions of the USA. For instance (according to Labov, cited in [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midland_American_English) Wikipedia article) /aʊ/ is fronted to [æʊ] in Midland American English.

Comment: I understand it's not really classified as [æ].Then what do we call this British pronunciation of [aʊ] as in OED? It's neither Australian nor Midland American English but presumably standard British English. I actually hear the same [aʊ] pronunciation here in New York where some people say either council, counsel or counselor in much like [æ] + [u] sound.

Comment: You can call it anything you want, really - IPA symbols are just notation, and get used in different conventional ways by different people. The IPA has a diacritic for fronting, a + under the character, so perhaps you could write the diphthong as [a̟ʊ] to show that it's slightly fronted.